# Pythonic way to ensure unicode in python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm working on porting a library so that it is compatible with both python 2 and 3.  The library receives strings or string-like objects from the calling application and I need to ensure those objects get converted to unicode strings.

In python 2 I can do:

```
unicode_x = unicode(x)
```

In python 3 I can do:

```
unicode_x = str(x)
```

However, the best cross-version solution I have is:

```
def ensure_unicode(x):
  if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    return unicode(x)
  return str(x)
```

which certainly doesn't seem great (although it works).  Is there a better solution?

I am aware of `unicode_literals` and the `u` prefix but both of those solutions do not work as the inputs come from clients and are not literals in my library.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't re-invent the compatibility layer wheel. Use the [`six` compatibility layer](http://pythonhosted.org/six/), a small one-file project that can be included with your own:

> Six supports every Python version since 2.6. It is contained in only one Python file, so it can be easily copied into your project. (The copyright and license notice must be retained.)

It includes a [`six.text_type()` callable](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.text_type) that does exactly this, convert a value to Unicode text:

```
import six

unicode_x = six.text_type(x)
```

In the [project source code](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/784c6a213c4527ea18f86a800f51bf16bc1df5bc/six.py?at=default) this is defined as:

```
import sys

PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
# ...

if PY3:
    # ...
    text_type = str
    # ...

else:
    # ...
    text_type = unicode
    # ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `six.text_type` should suffice virtually always, just like the accepted answer says.

On a side note, and FYI, you *could* get yourself into trouble in Python 3 if you somehow feed a `bytes` instance to it, (although this should be really hard to do).

**CONTEXT**

`six.text_type` is basically an alias for `str` in Python 3:

```
>>> import six
>>> six.text_type
<class 'str'>
```

Surprisingly, using `str` to cast `bytes` instances gives somewhat unexpected results:

```
>>> six.text_type(b'bytestring')
"b'bytestring'"
```

Notice how our string just got mangled? Straight from `str`'s [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> Passing a `bytes` object to `str()` without the encoding or errors
>   arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string
>   representation.

That is, `str(...)` will actually call the object's `__str__` method, unless you pass an `encoding`:

```
>>> b'bytestring'.__str__()
"b'bytestring'"
>>> six.text_type(b'bytestring', encoding='utf-8')
'bytestring'
```

Sadly, if you do pass an `encoding`, "casting" regular `str` instances will no longer work:

```
>>> six.text_type('string', encoding='utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

On a somewhat related note, casting `None` values can be troublesome as well:

```
>>> six.text_type(None)
'None'
```

You'll end up with a `'None'` string, literally. Probably not what you wanted.

**ALTERNATIVES**

1. **Just use six.text_type.** Really. There's nothing to worry about unless you interact with `bytes` on purpose. Make sure to check for `None`s before casting though.
2. **Use [Django's `force_text`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding).** Safest way out of this madness if you happen to be working on a project that's already using Django 1.x.x.
3. **Copy-paste Django's `force_text` to your project.** Here's a [sample implementation](https://gist.github.com/alexpizarroj/2061a7e723f5fe896dcfac8ccf761446).

For either of the Django alternatives, keep in mind that `force_text` allows you to specify `strings_only=True` to neatly preserve `None` values:

```
>>> force_text(None)
'None'
>>> type(force_text(None))
<class 'str'>

>>> force_text(None, strings_only=True)
>>> type(force_text(None, strings_only=True))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Be careful, though, as it won't cast several other primitive types as well:

```
>>> force_text(100)
'100'
>>> force_text(100, strings_only=True)
100
>>> force_text(True)
'True'
>>> force_text(True, strings_only=True)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

If `six.text_type(b'foo') -> "b'foo'"` in Python 3 is not what you want as mentioned in Alex's answer, probably you want `six.ensure_text()`, available in six v1.12.0+.

```
In [17]: six.ensure_text(b'foo')
Out[17]: 'foo'
```

Ref: https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.ensure_text